# Assigning shorter vector to a longer column in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
a<-matrix(NA,ncol=10,nrow=10)
```

and a vector:

```
b<-sample(1:100,3)
```

I would like to fill the first column on the matrix with the vector b.

The length of the column is 10 but the vector is only of length 3.

IS there a way to fill the column with the vector and leave the remaining slots empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by fill that the vector `b` gets recycled when it runs out of elements, you can use the following:

```
a[,1] <- rep(b,ceiling(ncol(a)/length(b)))[1:nrow(a)]
```

In case you just want to modify the number of row entries given by the length of `b` use

```
a[1:length(b),1] <- b
```